# Retrieving data between two dates from Access database using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I want to display data from a database in a datagridview. I am getting error on `da.Fill(ds, "SAMPLE")`  with "data type mismatch error". Please see screenshot.
My date formats are 'short date' both datetimepicker and database values.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Recto D Sanchez Jr\Documents\sample.accdb"
Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Dim source1 As New BindingSource

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from SAMPLE where [LOGDATE] between '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' And '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "'", MyConn)
    da.Fill(ds, "SAMPLE")
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view
End Sub
```

End Class

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXiSC.png)

Comment: have you tried removing `"SAMPLE"` ?

Comment: Tried that. Same error. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your DateTimePicker controls already deal with proper DateTime values you might have better luck using a *parameterized query* like this:

```vb
MyConn = New OleDbConnection(connString)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [SAMPLE] WHERE [LOGDATE] Between ? And ?", MyConn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DateTimePicker2.Value.Date)
da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "SAMPLE")
```

It would save you the trouble of dealing with different date formats, delimiting date literals, and other potential pitfalls.

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from SAMPLE where [LOGDATE] between #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & "# And #" & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & "#", MyConn)
```